# Creating a login form to submit to backend

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have three HTML elements that are labeled, and three corresponding variables. Each variable is referenced later on a button `onClick` with the hopes that when the JavaScript function is used, it will use those variables.

This way, someone can type in their login name and password, which will then be submitted to my backend, and a unique login ID created.

Oddly, when I change all the submitted information to generic "testuser", it successfully submits and gives me user data. So I know the connection is working and the JavaScript functions are working. But when I change the generic "testuser" to a variable, like `usernameInput`, I get a console saying:

`"WebSocket send: {"displayName":{},"password":{},"userName": {},"@class":".RegistrationRequest","requestId":"1511903088030_3"}"`

Where is my input data?  I entered "Billy Bob" on the HTML element!

Here is the code that I'm working on:

```
<!--Generic Login Features below-->
<label for="username">User Name</label><input id="usernameInput"/>
<var username = usernameInput>
<label for="password">Password</label><input id="passwordInput"/>
<var password = passwordInput>
<label for="displayname">Displayname</label><input id="displaynameInput"/>
<var password = displaynameInput>

<button onClick='gamesparks.registrationRequest(usernameInput, passwordInput, displaynameInput, registerResponse)'>Register</button>
<button onClick='gamesparks.authenticationRequest(usernameInput, passwordInput, loginResponse)'>Login</button>
<button onClick='gamesparks.accountDetailsRequest(accountDetailsResponse)'>Account Details</button>
```

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: `<var username = usernameInput>` and the other two like it do nothing. In HTML, they simply denote the semantics of a programming variable for presentation purposes as page content, but they do not actually create variables for programming purposes. Those lines do not create JavaScript variables. Where is your form element? Please show your JavaScript as well

Comment: JavaScript is utilized on front and back end.  It would be several hundred lines total and all of it would be irrelevant.  Can you specify what JavaScript you'd like me to show?  Likewise, I don't have a form element.  Do I need one?

Comment: Yes, you absolutely need a `form` element to encapsulate all the form fields and correctly gather up their data. You don't typically have separate buttons to send individual pieces of data, a `form` allows you to gather up all the data and send it as one unit. Also, if you don't post the JavaScript (i.e. the code for `gamesparks.registrationRequest`) we can't tell you anything about what may be wrong there.

Comment: JavaScript you requested:GameSparks.prototype.registrationRequest = function(displayName, password, userName, onResponse )
{
    var request = {};
  request["displayName"] = displayName;
  request["password"] = password;
  request["userName"] = userName;
    gamesparks.sendWithData("RegistrationRequest", request, onResponse);

Comment: Don't place the code in a comment. Update your question with that code included in it please.

Comment: I'm pursuing the following a modal form.  The code exceeds the limit for me to place in a comment.  I'll comment an update once testing is complete.

Comment: You don't understand. **Don't** place the code in a comment. Edit your question and add the code to that.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML is wrong**

**Scott is correct**, your Html is wrong. Instead of

```
<var username = usernameInput>
```

Use a function to read the values of the input fields using plain JavaScript.

`document.getElementById('usernameInput').value`

` will provide the text inserted in that input field and similarly for the others too.

Comment: Following your direction precisely yielded no change in my outcome.  I replaced <var username = usernameInput> with document.getElementById('usernameInput').value  This yielded the same result.  After adding </>, renaming 'usernameInput' to match each desired input, it still didn't work.  I even tried replacing usernameInput in my function with your line of code (both with my corrections and without) and it still didn't work.